# What kind of ports are these?

Tags: camera, cables

I just got this camera as a present as the preowner does not need it anymore.

I would like to know which cables fit these slots (and eventually what they are for).

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit:

The ports appear to be a micro-HDMI and a "multi connector".

Comment: It may be helpful if you could tell us the model and the maker of the camera - it's really difficult to guess just from one shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there are certainly people who can identify the ports from looking at them, it is sometimes the case that cameras use proprietary connections with standard-seeming connectors. Rather than this method of investigation, it'd be better to start with the brand and model number of the camera and then to find the manual online — this is easily done with *any* major (or minor but legitimate) brand camera made in the last two decades. The manual ­will explain. (There will likely be a labeled diagram in the first few pages identifying all of the controls, dials, switches, and ports.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the manufacturer's website where you can download owner's manuals.  In the manual there will be specific details as to the names of the ports and how they're used.